# CSS display inline block not showing divs on the same line

Tags: html, css

Here's my div:

```css
.results {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
}

#order-title-select {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 20px;
  font-size: 16px !important;
  margin-top: 25px !important;
}

#order-select {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 8px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 23px;
  border: 1px solid #FD8907;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #555;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="results" id="order" onChange={(event)=> this.handleSelect(event,"order")}>
  <h3 id="order-title-select">{t('list.order')}</h3>
  <select id="order-select">
    <option value="Newest publications">{t('list.newest')}</option>
    <option value="Oldest publications">{t('list.oldest')}</option>
    <option value="Ascending order">{t('list.lowest')}</option>
    <option value="Descending order">{t('list.highest')}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

I want the h3 and select elements to be adjacent to one another. 
Turns out it looks like this:

[image]

And also why does the text inside the select look like that??

Comment: your code is not working, Can you please add your full code (with jquery event) and what your actual issue? You want add the h3 tag inside the text ?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Output]

CSS

```
.results {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 50%;
    }

    #order-title-select {
        margin-left: 20px;
        font-size: 16px !important;
        margin-top: 25px !important;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    #order-select {
        display: inline-block;
        /* float: right; */
        margin-left: 8px;
        margin-right: 10px;
        margin-top: 23px;
        border: 1px solid #FD8907;
        border-radius: 5px;
        color: #555;
        font-family: inherit;
        font-size: inherit;
        box-shadow: none;
    }
```

Added **display: inline-block** to  #order-title-select and removed the float: right from  #order-title-select

`display:inline-block;` is ignored due to the `float:right;`. If 'float' has a value other than 'none', the box is floated and 'display' is treated as 'block' so please avoid using the `display:inline-block` and `float:right` together.

Comment: There is an image attached which was inferred from your explanation and code.
{t('list.newest')} appears as the real data is not available.

Comment: Regarding text in the select dropdown as per the image, it appears to be line-height issue, the css used to modify the select-dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

I adapted your code and it works, and I put the title to the left but if you move it below the select in the ul then it will appear on the right. Style it further to suit your needs.

This inline-list technique is used for navigation menus and other places where you want to better align different types of content like icons and text, for example.

Your select looks like it has too much padding applied to it which will start to obscure the option text. Make sure there's little to no padding there so all text shows.

```css
.results {
  // display: inline-block;
  // width: 50%;
}

#order-title-select {
  // float: right;
  // margin-left: 20px;
  // font-size: 16px !important;
  // margin-top: 25px !important;
}

#order-select {
  // display: inline-block;
  // float: right;
  // margin-left: 8px;
  // margin-right: 10px;
  // margin-top: 23px;
  border: 1px solid #FD8907;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #555;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.inline-list {
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

.inline-list li {
display: inline-block;
float: left;
line-height: 1;
// outline: 1px dotted violet;
}

.inline-list li h3 {
display: inline-block;
margin: 0;
padding: 0 1em 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="results" id="order">
<ul class="inline-list">
<li><h3 id="order-title-select">H3 Title</h3></li>
<li>
<form>
  <select id="order-select">
    <option value="Newest publications">Newest publications</option>
    <option value="Oldest publications">Oldest publications</option>
    <option value="Ascending order">Ascending order</option>
    <option value="Descending order">Descending order</option>
  </select>
</form>
</li>
</ul>
  

</div>
```